# Shut down of a Rails app on Amazon EC2 because of MySQL memory limit?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My Rails app stopped to work, just like that. I didn't deploy any new code for the past days.
The app is running on Micro instance (probably, but I cannot check it as Amazon EC2 console return just a blank page, what a day).

when I run on EC2 (Ubuntu system) `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  4.8G  2.7G  65% /
udev            288M  8.0K  288M   1% /dev
tmpfs           119M  180K  118M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            296M     0  296M   0% /run/shm
```

The **udev** shows no free space...

When I try to restart nginx, I get this error message:

```
*** [err :: IP] master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

When I check **unicorn.stderr.log**, I see there this issue:

```
I, [2013-10-29T10:20:10.358442 #5963]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/home/my_name/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/client.rb:58:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111) (Mysql2::Error)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I had the same problem when running Jenkins on a micro instance, have you tried upgrading it to a small instance just to see if it fixes it?

Comment: I cannot access the Amazon AWS EC2 console... still blank page as in Chrome as in Safari. Can I downgrade then?

Comment: You done need console. You can use [Elastic Fox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elasticfox/) or [ec2 commandline tools](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). AWS means Amazon Web Services. Its an API.You can even call the bare web service if you know how to.

Comment: Is your mysql running? it is listening on the unix socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`? Are you using socket in your `database.yml`? Post output of `top` command. Also `ps aux | grep mysql` and `ps aux | grep nginx`

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue some time back, I've moved the log files for mysql to '/mnt'. Log was getting heavy and as a result to execute the query there was not enough temporary space available. I'm sure 100% this will solve your issue. Also then you need to edit your `my.cnf` file for directing where to log the logs.

Take `mysql` backup first before proceding

Hope it will help you